# Cómo parar una hebra desde Activity en Android

Tags: java, android, hilos, socket

estoy realizando una app para enviar y recibir un texto de forma periódica mediante dos hebras. En el caso de que no reciba nada, quiero que desde la Activity se paren ambas hebras. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void run() {

    try{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(puerto);
        int contador=0;
        while(!end){
            try{
                ss.setSoTimeout(6000);
                Socket s=ss.accept();

                BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                stringData=input.readLine();
                output.flush();
                contador++;

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                output.close();
                s.close();
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                end=true;
            }

        }
        ss.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Eso sería para la hebra que recibe datos. Cuando pasan 6 segundos y no se recibe nada, salta la excepción. El código de la activity es el siguiente:

buttonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

```
        public void onClick(View view) {

             dirIP=editTextDirIP.getText().toString();

            hebraRecibir.start();
            hebraEnviar.start();

            while(comprobacion){
                if(ThreadRecibir.isEnd()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"la hebra se ha parado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    comprobacion=false;
                    hebraRecibir.interrupt();
                    hebraEnviar.interrupt();
                }
            }



        }
    });
```

Al pulsar el botón el botón y entrar en el while, se va comprobando el valor de true correspondiente a la hebra, pero no funciona bien. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias